# Same Tree | leetcode wrong complexity analysis of the solution

Tags: python, tree

I have one question regarding the space complexity analysis of the solution of the leetcode problem: 100. Same Tree

The problem: 
Given two binary trees, write a function to check if they are the same or not. Two binary trees are considered the same if they are structurally identical and the nodes have the same value.

The solution code:

```
from collections import deque
class Solution:
    def isSameTree(self, p, q):
        """
        :type p: TreeNode
        :type q: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """    
        def check(p, q):
            # if both are None
            if not p and not q:
                return True
            # one of p and q is None
            if not q or not p:
                return False
            if p.val != q.val:
                return False
            return True

        deq = deque([(p, q),])
        while deq:
            p, q = deq.popleft()
            if not check(p, q):
                return False

            if p:
                deq.append((p.left, q.left))
                deq.append((p.right, q.right))

        return True
```

My question:

The space complexity analysis of the solution in Leetcode says that it's O(N) for completely unbalanced tree, to keep a deque. However, I think the space complexity is definitely not O(N). I use the following example to show why: Assume that root = 1, root.left = 2, root.left.left = 3, root.left.left.left = 4, N is None. Below are the different stages of deque. For each stage, we popleft one item and add two except when we meet N.

[1]->[2,N]->[N,3,N]->[3,N]->[N,4,N]->[4,N]->[N,N,N]

As you can see from the deque above, the size never reaches N (where N is the number of nodes)

I can tell the space complexity of this algorithm is not O(N) (Am I right?), but I can't tell for sure what it is.